# How do I properly manage memory when using COM objects in VB?

Tags: memory-management, com, vb6

Can somebody please explain how the memory allocation/de-allocation occurs when we passing values between COM object and VB.

My Concerns are:
1.

```
IMyInterface::Method1 ([in] BSTR* pVal, [in] SAFEARRAY(BSTR)* pArray);
```

do we need to free the allocated memory for above parameters inside COM object ?

2.

```
IMyInterface::Method2 ([in, out] BSTR* pVal);
```

In this case, Will the VB take care of freeing memory for the COM return values ? (COM object allocates memory for these return values)

3.

```
IProxy_MyInterface::Event1 ([in] BSTR* pVal);
```

Once the event is handled inside VB, again, will de-allocation of memory of parameters be taken care by VB ?

Appreciate your help.

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Read official docs (`Allocating and Releasing Memory for a BSTR`):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xda6xzx7.aspx

Here is description of all your cases.

Answer (score 1):

`[in]` parameters must be allocated by the caller and freed by the caller unless the API documentation specifically says otherwise.

The `[in, out]` parameter is less clear, since this is a BSTR* it's possible that the BSTR that you pass in will be freed and a different BSTR returned, so you should free the BSTR that is returned rather than the one you passed in.

`[out]` and `[out, retVal]`, imply a transfer of ownership of the memory, the function allocates the memory and the caller is then responsible for freeing the memory.

For BSTR in C/C++ COM you would use `SysAllocString` and `SysFreeString` to allocate and free.

Comment: thanks for the clarification, If I use "[out]/ [out, retVal] BSTR*", then is it callee's responsibility to free the memory ? I think it is so, since once a value is returned, caller has no control over the function. Please explain.

Answer (score 0):

VB6 has three cases of string parameter declaration -- `ByVal param As String`, `ByRef param As String` and `Function() As String`. First one in IDL maps to `[in] BSTR param`, second one to `[in, out] BSTR *param`, third one to `[out, retval] BSTR *retval`.

There is no way VB6 can declare `[in] BSTR *`, nor `[out] BSTR *` params but it can still consume these i.e. it can call methods (on a VC) class that has params declared as out-only or any other IDL supported way.

Also note that `BSTR` itself is a typedef'd pointer, something like `wchar_t *`, so `BSTR *` is actually `wchar **`. The IDL needs an pointer for out params so you can't declare `[out] int param` and `[out] BSTR param` is also strange.

Once `[in] BSTR *` confusion is clear (it's needless weird double indirection required for out params but not for input only), the simple rule is that once you have a * in the param declaration then the caller has to free it after the method call if it's not NULL already.

`[in, out] SAFEARRAY(BSTR)* pArray` maps to `ByRef pArray() As String` in VB6 and you can't change this to `ByVal` i.e. the * is required by VB6 so it can't be in-only and the caller has to deallocate the safe array. The is no in-only safe array.